# I wanna speed things up while concatenating many media files

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to concatenate many files using concat demuxer.
Problem is a portion of those files have different tbn from the others.

So, I followed an answer by @sr9yar at:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31691943/ffmpeg-concat-poduces-dts-out-of-order-errors

Change the tbn values, then concatenate them.

If I have to change only a file, then it's ok. But there are many files that have to be adjusted, It's too much hassle.

The command I've just used looks like

```
ffmpeg -i "S5M7\S5M7_24 to 9.mp4" -i "S5M7\S5M7_29 to 11_2.mp4" -i "S5M7\S5M7_211_2 to 14.mp4" -i "S5M7\S5M7_2after 1.mp4" -video_track_timescale 1000 -c copy -map 0 "S5M7\S5M7_24 to 9.mp4" -video_track_timescale 1000 -c copy -map 1 "S5M7\S5M7_29 to 11_2.mp4" -video_track_timescale 1000 -c copy -map 2 "S5M7\S5M7_211_2 to 14.mp4" -video_track_timescale 1000 -c copy -map 3 "S5M7\S5M7_2after 1.mp4"
```

It's daily tasks, so I have to go through this again and again and again.

So I wonder

- If I can tell concat demuxer to change tbn value before concatenate them
- Or If FFmpeg accept regular expression as an input or output arguments
- Or any other suggestion to make it done more efficiently

Comment: Give me a few days to get this fixed in ffmpeg.

Comment: All right. I'll look forward to hearing from you.